# use the name of the field instead of index in list array in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `getvalue` object that contains a price list which consists of 5 items.  I need to get the value of one of the elements. I can get the value by index:

```
 return (getValue1.ValuationPrices[4].Value.ToString());
```

Instead of using `4` (the index) I would like to use the name of the field. Can I do that?

More detail:

[image]

I want to say if PriceType is "Wholesale" return the value that is 18289

that is the answer to this question:

```
  foreach (var item in getValue1.ValuationPrices)
            {
                if (item.PriceType == ServiceReference1.PriceType.Wholesale)
                {

                    carValue= item.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: It's not super clear what you're asking.  Please show us the classes for your data types.

Comment: Please show us what you'd like to do in pseudo-code and we'll probably be able to help more.

Comment: You may want to consider using a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: It seems you need a `Dictionary<string, yourObject>`

Comment: I'm afraid that that's a fairly incoherent question.  Do you mean that you want to search for an item by specifying the value of one of its properties?  Unless the indexer of your ValuationPrices collection has been overloaded to take a key as well as an index then that would mean using something like this: `var valuationPrice = getValue1.ValuationPrices.FirstOrDefault(vp => vp.SomeProperty == someValue);`  That variable will then contain the first matching object if there is one or null if there isn't.  That's a guess at what you want though.  A clear explanation is still in order.

Comment: @please look at the image I have uploaded and more detail in the question I still have not got answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can either change your array to `Dictionary<string, yourType>` or use LINQ to perform linear search for your object by name:

```
return getValue1.ValuationPrices.First(x => x.Name == "myName").Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you wish him exception if "myName" is missing?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek what is x?

Comment: Local variable within lambda expression.

Comment: when I wrote like this:     var test = getValue1.ValuationPrices.First(x => x.PriceType).Value.ToString(); it gave me this error on x.PriceType: cannot implicitly convert type 'webservice1.servicereference1.proceType' to bool

Comment: The error is correct. You have to compare `x.PriceType` to something to get proper predicate.

Comment: I want to say for example if pricetype="test" get the value

Comment: so use `x => x.PriceType == "test"`.

Comment: I write this:   var test = getValue1.ValuationPrices.First(x => x.PriceType == "test");  it gave me this error: operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'webservice1.servicereference1.pricetype' and 'string'

Comment: Which part of the error message you don't understand? If `PriceType` is not a string, you can't compare it to `string`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek when I have  var test = getValue1.ValuationPrices.First(x => x.PriceType = "Wholesale"); again it gave me the error cannot implicitly convert 'string' to ...

Comment: price type is string.

Comment: instead of 4 in this:     return (getValue1.ValuationPrices[4].Value.ToString());  I like to have the name of the filed that is PriceType.

Comment: view image here: 

http://postimg.org/image/fuh5niigt/
 
I wan to say if PriceType is "Wholesale" return the value that is 18289

Comment: OK, as I said '`PriceType`' is not a string. It would have been "Wholesale" on your screen if it was a string.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek so what is the solution after you see what I see in debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by adding an indexer property to the `ValuationPrices` type.

```
public ValuationPrice this[string name]
{
    get
    {
        return this.First(n => n.Name == value);
    }
}
```

Then you would be able to write `getvalue1.ValuationPrices["fieldName"]`.

The implementation of the indexer property will vary depending on the internal structure of your classes, but hopefully this gives you some idea of the syntax used to implement the indexer.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot helped quite a bit... people can't guess what your classes look like internally. Your comment to Marcin indicates that `PriceType` might be an enumeration. So assuming:

- `PriceType` is actually an enum, not a string
- The `PriceType` you're searching for is *guaranteed* to be in that collection at once and one time only

This should work:

```
return getValue1.ValuationProces.Single(x => x.PriceType == PriceType.WholeSale).Value.ToString();
```

This is basically the same as Marcin's - if I'm right about `PriceType` being an enum and this works, then you should just accept his answer and move on.